# jena Triples not terminated by DOT

Tags: jena, fuseki

when I start jena-fuseki server, it occur in a error that Triples not terminated by DOT. but my nt file end by dot for each triple. why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc78G.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dH5L.png)

Comment: Pleas show the data - without seeing that, the question can't be answered. Also what is the exact error message?

Comment: i have upload the error image, thanks

Comment: "Configuration file: ../../config.ttl" "Failed reading the assembler description". The error is in a Fuseki configuration file, not the data. Line 29. (+ it is a qute old version of Fuseki 3.5.0, current is 3.17.0)